# Guess card with same color

Tags: probability

> I have a standard 52 card deck (26 red and 26 black). One by one, I draw cards from the deck and place them face up in front of you (without putting them back). At any point, you may stop me and say a color. If the next two cards I draw both have that color, you win. Otherwise, you lose. What is the optimal strategy?

Denote $f(a,b)$ is probability of win when there are $a$ red and $b$ black left. We have following results:
$$f(1,1) = 0;\ f(a,b) = f(b,a);\ f(a,0) = 1, a>1.$$
When we stop, the probability of win is
$$\dfrac{a}{a+b}*\dfrac{a-1}{a+b-1};$$
When we continue, the probability of win is
$$\dfrac{a}{a+b} f(a-1,b) + \dfrac{b}{a+b} f(a,b-1).$$
Therefore the iteration relation is

$$f(a,b) = max\left(\dfrac{a}{a+b}*\dfrac{a-1}{a+b-1},\quad \dfrac{a}{a+b} f(a-1,b) + \dfrac{b}{a+b} f(a,b-1)\right).$$
But I don't know how to get the closed formula or further simplify the representation?

Comment: I'd just compute it numerically, using your formula. The boundary conditions are clear, so backwards induction from the boundary should work out.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3853598/304635